# How to Retain the perpendicular part of a vector

Tags: vectors

I am trying to evaluate this expression $[(x - xi)]\bot$n where n is a normalized normal. I am told the expression $\bot$ means only the part perpendicular to n is retained. (x, xi and n are vectors)

Comment: What is $n$ here? Is it equal to $i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard interpretation of $(x-xi)\perp n$ is "$(x-xi)$ is perpendicular to $n$".

If you are looking for an operation which retains the component perpendicular to $n$ (i.e. removes the component parallel to $n$), use this:
$$v = (x-xi) - ((x-xi)\cdot n) n$$
$v$ is now perpendicular to $n$: $v\perp n$

Comment: Okay interesting. This would be different from using a cross product?

Comment: Yes. A cross product creates a vector perpendicular to two given vectors. It does not retain the component of one vector which is perpendicular to the other.